# Keep checking if S3 file is available

Tags: bash, shell, amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I was trying to keep checking if a particular S3 file is available or not

I had written a code.

```
s3path="s3://Data/logFiles/myFile"
while true
do
  s3cmd info $s3path >/dev/null 2>&1
  if [[ $? -eq 0 ]] then
     echo "Done"
     break
  fi
 done
```

But its giving errors. While executing am getting error saying syntax error near unexpected token `then'.

Please help to reolve it

Comment: You missed the `;` (or newline) between `]]` and `then`. Also you could just use `while ! s3cmd info $s3path >/dev/null 2>&1; do sleep ##; done` and yes, you want the sleep or you are busy looping and will eat up *huge* amounts of resources.

Comment: Also http://www.shellcheck.net/ would have caught this error for you. (Though it also spits out a bunch of unrelated issues caused by the parsing problem.)